How to implement gesture-controlled animation for toggling the number of items displayed per row in a photo album app similar to Apple's?
zooming animation example
How to achieve the zoom-in and zoom-out transition animation similar to Apple's Photos app?
How to implement using a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout and add gestures to achieve this?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to review [ask]. First step should always be searching. If you head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for uicollectionview pinch zoom you'll find many examples, discussions, articles, tutorials, etc.
